# Which "href" value should I use?

Tags: html, css

```
 <h5 class="x"> Higher <span class="place"> BUSMS </span></h5>
```

I want to put hyperlinks in "BUSMS".
Both are working .Which one should I use?and why?

```
 <h5 class="x"> Higher <span class="place"><a href="url"> BUSMS </a></span></h5>
                                    or
 <h5 class="x"> Higher <a href="url"> <span class="place"> BUSMS </span> </a></h5>
```

Comment: both are valid, but I preffer the second one

Comment: How about `<a href="url" class="place"> BUSMS </a>` ?

Comment: Markup should be _semantic_, so the answer depends on the _meaning_. I would tend to `<a><span class="place"> Words </span></a>` because most of the time the `<a>` is not part of the _place_, but the _place_ is part of the _link_.